# Series converging to the number e in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to calculate serie 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! +...+1/n! in C++?
I have an outline:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, fat;
    float soma = 0.0;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {

        fat = 1;
        soma += 1 / fat;
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            fat *= j;
        }
    }
    cout << soma << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you don't ned to recalculate the whole factorial each time

Comment: Need to post this article since we're computing the factorial each time... http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an integer division right here:

```
soma += 1 / fat;
```

change it to this:

```
soma += 1. / fat;
```

Also be aware that your implementation is very vulnerable to integer overflow when `n` gets large.

Here's the working version. There were 2 more errors:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, fat;
    float soma = 1.0;   //  Change to 1.0
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {

        fat = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            fat *= j;
        }
        soma += 1. / fat;      //  Move this to after the loop.
    }
    cout << soma << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to recompute the factorial at each step.

Comment: And how to use big n, example, n = 1000?

Comment: `n = 12` is as large as you can go before you get integer overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Keep a running term and add that to the result:

```
double result = 1.0;
double term = 1.0;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i != N; ++i)
{
    term /= i;
    result += term;
}

return result;
```

You can compute any `exp(x)` with a small modification.